# Can't view all the schema's in SQL sever while importing the source tables in informatica power center

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have to import a specific source table from the source database. I could see only a few schemas and not all (as there are thousands of), hence could not select desired table, so I am specifying the table in search box. But it does not show up anything. I tried using schema.tablename and different combinations but in vain. Infact, when I try searching for the tables that are already visible, they doesn't show up. i used the same credentials that i used to create schema and tables. though im not getting those required schema and table.  ANy help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the Import Tables dialog box select "All" in Show owners:

[image]

Comment: Even then it shows only the limited schema's. i ensured the credentials that i have used to create a connection is the one that i used to create the schema and tables.. clueless.. please help

Comment: Which database do you have? Are you able to see the schemas fron your db client?

Comment: Most likely you do not have permission on the tables in other schemas

Comment: I have SQL server 2012 DB. as you said, Permission might be the issue. what sort of permission does it requires?

Comment: DB user that you use to connect need to have permission to access the schema / tables you need.